# How to fix this (un)expected result from atbegshi

Tags: page-breaking, output-routine, atbegshi, shipout

Please how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{atbegshi}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo 1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Foo 2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Foo 3}
\AtBeginShipoutNext{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
     \put(100,-100){\fbox{\bfseries AAA}}%
}}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

`\fbox{\bfseries AAA}` should be in the background of page 2. I mean same page with `\section{Foo 3}`.

Please I am looking for a generic solution if possible.

Comment: it doesn't seem that surprising, you specified text to be at the next shipout so next time tex considers a page break that gets added to the page, it so happened it then decided to only output the text before the section and hold the section heading over to the next page. tex page breaking always works in this asynchronous way, considering more material than fits on one page

Comment: This is why section headings use the `\mark` system so when making up the page tex has access to the first and last marks that actually appear on the page, is there any reason you can't use `\markboth{AAAA}` here with a page style that sets the marks at a suitable position

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i did not think in `\mark` because the problem is not related to section, as you noticed in your first comment it's because tex's page breaking mechanism. I'll try `\mark` it's good idea.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle of course i can't use `\markboth{AAAA}` but i can try some thing like that

Comment: not sure why the "of course" (if you are not using marks in the headings, which is the default for article as in the MWE, the standard latex marks should be available) but there are variants or even use of etex mark classes

Comment: well my class is book, and yes i mean i will try the variants.